# Android org.apache.hhtp.NoHttpRsponseException:The target server failed to respond error on login screen

Tags: android, mysql, authentication

I've created a login screen but when I put the username and password in it displays 'org.apache.hhtp.NoHttpRsponseException:The target server failed to respond' within the android emulator.

I'm new to android and so i'm not sure how to fix this.

It's not showing any errors in eclipse so could my php file be the problem?

**Here's my code**

```
<?php

$un=$_POST['username'];
$pw=$_POST['password'];

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('app');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = ‘$un’ AND password = ‘$pw’';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ('Unable to verify user because : ' .                                 
mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 

echo 1; 
} 
else { 

// print status message 
echo 0; 
}
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

thanks

Comment: login I think is a https request. Check your specifications..

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what your intent is with the above code but one thing to keep in mind is that your development machine and the android emulator have different IP addresses.  They are two different 'machines'.  In which case the use of localhost may not be correct.